# is it practical to use bit data type to store true/false into sql database?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

is it practical to use **bit** data type to store *true/false* value into sql database? I read that some people use **tinyint(1)** but I do not know why?, is it different in performance and more practical? is their any problem at the time of conversion to **Boolean** type?

Comment: I think you are not clear about different datatypes of sql..please read..and most probably people use bit datatype for true/false

Comment: @Vidhi could you guide me to a good reference about SQL datatypes

Comment: Go through with https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-data-types-reference/

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean by "practical"?

Comment: Generally it is best to use a bit, although it will use the same storage as a tinyint you won't accidentally set a field to something other than 1 or 0 which can be done with a tinyint. Some interfaces recognize and evaluate bit types to booleans such as ASP.NET

Comment: Also depends on what database product you are using. What database product are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By practical I assume you mean an advantage over using another method to store boolean values. SQL Server implicitly converts boolean values to `bit` type, so amongst the other benefits (largely being that using the `bit` type is stored as 1 byte, extremely efficient), it makes sense to use it since you're making less work for yourself, no need for defaults or constraints. `tinyint` however (also stored as 1 byte), can store values up to 255 naturally, and you will likely experience conversion errors when trying to implicitly convert boolean values from an application layer.

TL;DR Always use an appropriate type. `bit` type is appropriate for boolean values, therefore there's no reason **not** to use it.